# describing cyclic subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $f(x) = x + 1$, describe the cyclic subgroup $\{f\}$ of $S_{\mathbb{R}}$

I am stuck on how to go about this. I'm not even sure what $S_\mathbb{R}$ means. Is it the symmetric group of the real numbers?

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

$S_\mathbb{R}$ is most probably the symmetric group on $\mathbb{R}$, that is the set of bijections $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Since $f$ is the translation of $\mathbb{R}$ one unit to the right, the subgroup generated by $f$ is the set of all translations by an integer displacement (to the right when the displacement is positive and to the left when it is negative).

Answer (score 0):

Subgroup generated by $f$ contains all potentions of $f$, $$\langle f\rangle =\{f^n:n\in \mathbb{Z}\}.$$ 
Since $f^{-1}=x-1$, it is not hard to see that $$\langle f\rangle =\{ g: g(x)=x+n, n\in \mathbb{N}\}.$$